How to use a constant object like a literal type-hint?
I have a unique and constant object as a special value, which I would like to use for type-hints in different occasions.
Lets assume I have a situation like this:
NO_RESULT = object()

def foo() -> Hashable | ???:
   try:
      result : Hashable = res()
      return result
   except:
      return NO_RESULT

Here I would like to annotate the return value foo() -> Literal[NO_RESULT] | Hashable. However, this is not proper and I will get warnings as this is not a literal value.

I know I could use the following code and annotate it with NoResultType
NoResultType = NewType("NoResultType", object)
NO_RESULT = NoResultType(object())

However, this refers to instances of a type, and not a unique object, which is a semantic difference I do not want to have.

How do I have to modify NO_RESULT so that I can use it in type-hints as well as a variable?

That semantic difference simply does not exist for singleton types. None is an instance of NoneType (the only one), ... is an instance of EllipsisType (the only one, again). Typing authors decided to allow None as a shortcut for NoneType, but there's no support for user-defined singletons in the same fashion. Your NewType solution looks very nice, there are also a Enum way and less pretty plain class approach, but I don't see any reason to look further than what you have. Python's type system can't talk about instances, only about their types.

Enum with one element?

I'm not sure this is an improvement over Hashable | None. The use of None to indicate the lack of a value of a given type (indeed, it's primary purpose) is well enough established that I don't think inventing an additional sentinel has any real benefit. (Yes, it would be nicer if Python supported sum types, not just union types.)

Thank you. For now I go with the Enum, it is the closest to what I intended originally, just gives me a new class :/ . None is no option for me as res could just return None and I want a strong separation to this case.

@Daraan The other option would be to  either not include try/except within foo, or to have foo re-raise an exception of your choice, and have the caller handle that exception instead of conditonally checking for NO_RESULT

@nigh_anxiety in my case foo already is the exception handler (for special exceptions) that should not propagate outside. I did not want to include more clutter in the snipplet, also I want to use the type-hint then in other places.

Yes I think its similar enough to the question InSync referred to. Thank you. For further reading one can also check out PEP-661 which talks about this case and how it can be done currently.

Currently this is not directly supported. PEP 661 - Sentinel Values refers to this idea.
In the Rejected Ideas section one can find some workarounds that are class or object based. All have certain downsides.
For myself I choose the proposed Enum solution because it can be used with typing.Literal
from enum import Enum

class Result(Enum):
   NO_RESULT = object()
   
   def __repr__(self):
      # Optional to display it as <Result.NO_RESULT> instead of object
      return "<" self.__class__ + "." + self.name + ">"


def get_key(key: Hashable | Literal[Result.NO_RESULT]=Result.NO_RESULT):
   ...

